# Memory Fault while trimming the pointer string in C language

Tags: memory, segmentation-fault

I am getting the Memory Fault error while trimming the spaces from end of the string. Can anyone please help me to resolve the below code.

**code:**

```
 char* trimfun(char *st) {
    int i=0,j;
    /* Trim spaces and tabs from end:*/
    i=strlen(st)-1;
    while ((st[i]==' ')||(st[i]=='\t')) {   
        i--;    
     }

    if (i<(strlen(st)-1)) {
        st[i+1]='\0';
    }
    return st;
    // free (s);
    // free (st);
 }
```

Thanks
Ramki

Comment: looks fine from a glance, but you have two unreachable free's, unused j and undefined s.

Comment: Is one of the incoming strings perhaps not null terminated?

Answer (score 0):

What if the entire string `st` is white spaces?

In that case the `while` loop:

```
while((st[i]==' ')||(st[i]=='\t')) {    i--;    }
```

will not terminate at `i==0`!

This may be the cause of your seg-fault.

Try:

```
while ( ( i >= 0 ) && ( (st[i]==' ') || (st[i]=='\t') ) ) ) {
    i--;    
}
```